# Python assigning the string to the variable - Str object is not callable message

Tags: python, string, function, var, setattr

I have the following problem where

```
roles = models.StringField

def role(player):
    if player.rank == 1:
        return 'leader'
    else:
        return 'member'
```

Later I am trying to assign the role function outcome which is string to roles variable i.e.

```
for i in range(len(players)):
    players[i].roles = players[i].role()
    .....
```

However, I am getting the message that str function is not callable. I am new to python programming. Any help will be much appreciated. The function is working properly otherwise. I am using python 3.9.

I have used the `setattr` function by trying

```
for i in range(len(players)):
    name = 'roles'
    setattr(players[i], name, players[i].role())
    .....
```

However, still I am getting the same message that str function is not callable. Any idea how can I fix this.

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question!

Comment: Please also format with 4-space indent, as is customary for Python, and make sure you provide a [mcve]. Please, as a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Get out of the habit of using `for index in range(len(list)):`. Use `for item in list:`

Answer (score 0):

this error msg is a runtime error.
it means that `players[i].role` is a string not a function.
that means that somewhere is your app, you assigned a string value to `players[i].role`. so it is no longer a function.
this may be a typo (ie: you probably wrote
 `players[i].role = "blabla bla"` 
instead of
 `players[i].roles = "blabla bla"`)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Yes, as mentioned in the first block the role is assigned to each player by the def role (player) function. I now want to call the outcome of that function for each player which is a string i.e. "leader" or "member" and want to assign that value to my string variable named roles.

Comment: the code you uploaded is fine.but, as I mentioned, this may be a typo. so, the bug may be  in another area of your code. so, you should upload a full example that reproduce the error (eg: .py file or a zipped folder of the project) so that other developers can run it on their machine to debug it.